# vb.net code for ethernet comunication for Fatek Fbs PLC

Tags: vb.net, ethernet, plc

I'm going to write an application in VB.net for PC and then connect PC to Fatek FBs via Ethernet and control machine from PC. Can anybody send me an example code with communication PC-Fatek FBs?

Comment: Are you sure that VB.net is going to be the right environment for PLC development? Have you checked out these documents? http://www.avanti-software.co.uk/support/plcs/FB-Manual/ there is also some chat here about how it's unlikely you'll be able to use VB.net for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302450/plc-programing-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: VB.net will be applicatin works insted HMI. making complicate clculation is much easier in VB than in conventional HMI software. I have alredy tedted solution like this but using RS 232. Now I need use ethernet

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was wrong, here is an article about talking to Fatek plcs using .net :)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227990/Fatek-and-Facon-PLCs-Communication-Protocol-Serial

Comment: I have found this and try it. It works good but there is only code for RS communication. I need make communictiona via ethernet